# How to display this nested array with sub blocks?

Tags: docx, tinybutstrong

Single item of array:

```
array(3) {
  'name' =>
  string(19) "trigger_assignments"
  'description' =>
  string(67) "Maps trigger to hook and operation assignments from trigger.module."
  'fields' =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    array(3) {
      'name' =>
      string(4) "hook"
      'description' =>
      string(76) "Primary Key: The name of the internal Drupal hook; for example, node_insert."
      'type' =>
      string(7) "varchar"
    }
    [1] =>
    array(3) {
      'name' =>
      string(3) "aid"
      'description' =>
      string(36) "Primary Key: Action's {actions}.aid."
      'type' =>
      string(7) "varchar"
    }
    [2] =>
    array(3) {
      'name' =>
      string(6) "weight"
      'description' =>
      string(67) "The weight of the trigger assignment in relation to other triggers."
      'type' =>
      string(3) "int"
    }
  }
}
```

I can't display 'fields' array. It should be display in table, my code:

```
[c;block=begin; sub1=(fields)]
Nazwa tabeli: [c.name;]
[c.description;]
Lista pól tabeli:

Nazwa   Typ Opis
[c_sub1.name;block=tr]  [c_sub1.type;]  [c_sub1.description;]

[c;block=end]
```

The sample result is:

```
Nazwa tabeli: aggregator_category
Stores categories for aggregator feeds and feed items.
Lista pól tabeli:

Nazwa   Typ Opis
[c_sub1.name;block=tr]  [c_sub1.type;]  [c_sub1.description;]
```

So table with fields was not displayed.

Could someone give me any advixe?

Code:

```
$TBS->MergeBlock('c', $table);
```

`$table` has items like above inside.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14" xml:space="preserve">
 <w:body>
  <w:p w:rsidRDefault="00905443" w:rsidP="00273597">
   <w:r>
    <w:t>
    </w:t>
   </w:r>
  </w:p>
  <w:p w:rsidRDefault="00595A19" w:rsidP="00273597">
   <w:r>
    <w:t>
     Nazwa tabeli: aggregator_category
    </w:t>
   </w:r>
  </w:p>
  <w:p w:rsidRDefault="008248E2" w:rsidP="00273597">
   <w:r>
    <w:t>
     Stores categories for aggregator feeds and feed items.
    </w:t>
   </w:r>
  </w:p>
  <w:p w:rsidRDefault="00462CAC" w:rsidP="00273597">
   <w:r>
    <w:t>
     Lista pól tabeli:
    </w:t>
   </w:r>
  </w:p>
  <w:p w:rsidRDefault="00F53554" w:rsidP="00F53554">
   <w:pPr>
    <w:spacing w:after="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
    <w:rPr>
     <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
     <w:sz w:val="24"/>
     <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
    </w:rPr>
   </w:pPr>
  </w:p>
  <w:tbl>
   <w:tblPr>
    <w:tblpPr w:leftFromText="141" w:rightFromText="141" w:vertAnchor="text" w:horzAnchor="margin" w:tblpXSpec="center" w:tblpY="425"/>
    <w:tblW w:w="9606" w:type="dxa"/>
    <w:tblBorders>
     <w:top w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
     <w:left w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
     <w:bottom w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
     <w:right w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
     <w:insideH w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
     <w:insideV w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    </w:tblBorders>
    <w:tblLook w:val="01E0" w:firstRow="1" w:lastRow="1" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="1" w:noHBand="0" w:noVBand="0"/>
   </w:tblPr>
   <w:tblGrid>
    <w:gridCol w:w="2440"/>
    <w:gridCol w:w="1567"/>
    <w:gridCol w:w="5599"/>
   </w:tblGrid>
   <w:tr w:rsidTr="005C7EBF">
    <w:trPr>
     <w:trHeight w:hRule="exact" w:val="340"/>
     <w:tblHeader/>
    </w:trPr>
    <w:tc>
     <w:tcPr>
      <w:tcW w:w="2440" w:type="dxa"/>
      <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="C0C0C0"/>
      <w:vAlign w:val="center"/>
     </w:tcPr>
     <w:p w:rsidRDefault="00CE4402" w:rsidP="005E0ABE">
      <w:pPr>
       <w:spacing w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
       <w:jc w:val="center"/>
       <w:rPr>
        <w:b/>
       </w:rPr>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
       <w:rPr>
        <w:b/>
       </w:rPr>
       <w:t>
        Nazwa
       </w:t>
      </w:r>
     </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
     <w:tcPr>
      <w:tcW w:w="1567" w:type="dxa"/>
      <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="C0C0C0"/>
     </w:tcPr>
     <w:p w:rsidRDefault="00CE4402" w:rsidP="005E0ABE">
      <w:pPr>
       <w:spacing w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
       <w:jc w:val="center"/>
       <w:rPr>
        <w:b/>
       </w:rPr>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
       <w:rPr>
        <w:b/>
       </w:rPr>
       <w:t>
        Typ
       </w:t>
      </w:r>
     </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
     <w:tcPr>
      <w:tcW w:w="5599" w:type="dxa"/>
      <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="C0C0C0"/>
      <w:vAlign w:val="center"/>
     </w:tcPr>
     <w:p w:rsidRDefault="00CE4402" w:rsidP="005E0ABE">
      <w:pPr>
       <w:spacing w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
       <w:jc w:val="center"/>
       <w:rPr>
        <w:b/>
       </w:rPr>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
       <w:rPr>
        <w:b/>
       </w:rPr>
       <w:t>
        Opis
       </w:t>
      </w:r>
     </w:p>
    </w:tc>
   </w:tr>
   <w:tr w:rsidTr="005C7EBF">
    <w:trPr>
     <w:trHeight w:hRule="exact" w:val="521"/>
    </w:trPr>
    <w:tc>
     <w:tcPr>
      <w:tcW w:w="2440" w:type="dxa"/>
     </w:tcPr>
     <w:p w:rsidRDefault="005C7EBF" w:rsidP="005C7EBF">
      <w:pPr>
       <w:spacing w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
       <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Verdana" w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Verdana"/>
        <w:color w:val="000000"/>
        <w:sz w:val="18"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="18"/>
       </w:rPr>
       <w:t>
        [c_sub1.name;block=tr]
       </w:t>
      </w:r>
     </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
     <w:tcPr>
      <w:tcW w:w="1567" w:type="dxa"/>
     </w:tcPr>
     <w:p w:rsidRDefault="005C7EBF" w:rsidP="005C7EBF">
      <w:pPr>
       <w:spacing w:after="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
       <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Verdana" w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Verdana"/>
        <w:color w:val="000000"/>
        <w:sz w:val="18"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="18"/>
       </w:rPr>
       <w:t>
        [c_sub1.type;]
       </w:t>
      </w:r>
     </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
     <w:tcPr>
      <w:tcW w:w="5599" w:type="dxa"/>
     </w:tcPr>
     <w:p w:rsidRDefault="005C7EBF" w:rsidP="005C7EBF">
      <w:pPr>
       <w:spacing w:after="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
       <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Verdana" w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Verdana"/>
        <w:color w:val="000000"/>
        <w:sz w:val="18"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="18"/>
       </w:rPr>
       <w:t>
        [c_sub1.description;]
       </w:t>
      </w:r>
     </w:p>
    </w:tc>
   </w:tr>
  </w:tbl>
  <w:p w:rsidRDefault="00A927EE" w:rsidP="00273597">
   <w:pPr>
    <w:rPr>
     <w:rStyle w:val="Strong"/>
     <w:rFonts w:ascii="Verdana" w:hAnsi="Verdana"/>
     <w:color w:val="006600"/>
     <w:sz w:val="18"/>
     <w:szCs w:val="18"/>
     <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="FFFFFF"/>
    </w:rPr>
   </w:pPr>
  </w:p>
  <w:p w:rsidRDefault="00905443" w:rsidP="00273597">
   <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
     <w:rFonts w:ascii="Verdana" w:hAnsi="Verdana"/>
     <w:color w:val="000000"/>
     <w:sz w:val="18"/>
     <w:szCs w:val="18"/>
     <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="FFFFFF"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>
    </w:t>
   </w:r>
  </w:p>
  <w:sectPr>
   <w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838"/>
   <w:pgMar w:top="1417" w:right="1417" w:bottom="1417" w:left="1417" w:header="708" w:footer="708" w:gutter="0"/>
   <w:cols w:space="708"/>
   <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
  </w:sectPr>
 </w:body>
</w:document>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot replicate your result with the information you've given. Using these two test files your data printed like so:

```
<div>
Name: trigger_assignments<Br>
Maps trigger to hook and operation assignments from trigger.module.
<Br >List:
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Nazwa</td>
        <td>Typ</td>
        <td>Opis</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>hook</td>
        <td>varchar</td>
        <td>Primary Key: The name of the internal Drupal hook; for example, node_insert.</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>aid</td>
        <td>varchar</td>
        <td>Primary Key: Action's {actions}.aid.</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>weight</td>
        <td>int</td>
        <td>The weight of the trigger assignment in relation to other triggers.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br /><br />
</div>
```

test.php:

```
$test = array(
    array ('name' => "trigger_assignments", 
        'description' => "Maps trigger to hook and operation assignments from trigger.module.",
        'fields' => array(
             array('name' => "hook",
                 'description' => "Primary Key: The name of the internal Drupal hook; for example, node_insert.",
                 'type' =>  "varchar"),
              array('name' => "aid",
                  'description' => "Primary Key: Action's {actions}.aid.",
                  'type' =>  "varchar"),
              array('name' => "weight",
                  'description' => "The weight of the trigger assignment in relation to other triggers.",
                  'type' =>  "int")
        )
    )
);
include_once('includes/tbs_class.php');
$TBS = new clsTinyButStrong;

$TBS->LoadTemplate('test.html');
$TBS->MergeBlock('test', $test);

$TBS->Show();
```

And test.html:

```
<div>
[test;block=begin; sub1=(fields)]
Name: [test.name;]<Br>
[test.description;]
<Br >List:
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Nazwa</td>
        <td>Typ</td>
        <td>Opis</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>[test_sub1.name;block=tr]</td>
        <td>[test_sub1.type;]</td>
        <td>[test_sub1.description;]</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br /><br />
[test;block=end]
</div>
```

Don't know if that helps. Maybe you could give a little more info about your variable 'c' and your $TBS->mergeBlock() command?

Comment: Can you change your $TBS->Show() to $TBS->Show(OPENTBS_DEBUG_XML); and look to see if your [c_sub1] tags look ok in the XML that is output?

Comment: @Sarah.Kemp Could you try your example (I tried, no luck) on my array: http://pastebin.com/zQKnMpiA